# Prove the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ from $X \times X \to X$ is continuous when $X$ is given a weak topology.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, product-space, weak-topology

Let X be a Banach space. Prove the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ from $X \times X \to X$ is continuous when $X$ is given a weak topology.

Could anybody give me some hints to start?

Comment: $X$ is any topological vector space? What is your definition of "a weak topology"?

Comment: I am sorry, I forgot to write it: X is a Banach space and we define the weak topology as follows https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology

Comment: Then it's basically trivial as addition commutes with linear functionals and $X$ has the weak topology wrt continuous functionals. Nets are the easiest way to see this. If these cannot be used, consider what the natural base for the weak topology on $X$ and its product on $X \times X$ is.

Answer (score 2):

You have to say what topology you are using on $X \times X$. Assuming that you are using the product topology here is a simple proof: if $(x_i,y_i) \to (x,y)$ weakly and $f$ is a continuous linear functional then $x_i \to x$ and $y_i \to y$ weakly by definition of product topology. Hence $f(x_i) \to f(x)$ and $f(y_i) \to f(y)$ and  $f(x_i+y_i)=f(x_i)+f(y_i) \to f(x)+f(y)=f(x+y)$.

Remark: here $(x_i)$ and $(y_i)$ are nets. You can use sequences in the case of metrizable spaces but not in general.

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that for every weakly open subset $U$ of $X$ containing $x_0+y_0$, there exists weakly open subsets $V$, $W$ of $X$ containing respectively $x_0$ and $y_0$, such that if $x \in V$, $y \in W$, $x+y \in U$.

I suggest that you prove it when $U$ is some $\{y, \phi(y) < a\}$ where $a$ is a real number and $\phi \in X^*$. Then you can prove it when $U$ is a finite intersection of such subsets and from this address the general case.